# How to copy field multiple rows based on map of origin and destination ids

Tags: mysql

I want to copy values of specific table field from one list of ids (origin), to another list (destination). (note that for each couple there is a different value to copy).

**Original table:**

```
id  fieldA
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

**Destination table:**

```
id  fieldA
11  a
22  b
33  c
```

**Map list:**
This is list of ids I need to provide in my query

```
originIds   destinationIds
1           11
2           22
3           33
```

**State of destination table after update:**

This is the wanted results

```
id  fieldA
11  A
22  B
33  C
```

I would appreciate assistance with building such update query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either have a table to contain your mappings. Then:

```
update destination_table d
join mapping_table m on m.destination_id = d.id
join original_table o on o.id = m.origin_id
set d.fielda = a.fielda;
```

Or build it on-the-fly:

```
update destination_table d
join
(
  select 1 as origin_id, 11 as destination_id
  union all
  select 2 as origin_id, 22 as destination_id
  union all
  select 3 as origin_id, 33 as destination_id
) m on m.destination_id = d.id
join original_table o on o.id = m.origin_id
set d.fielda = a.fielda;
```